# how to pass selected value from dropdown to another dropdown in next page

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a form when user select value from dropdown it can direct them to another page.but in the next page I want the selected value to be pass to another dropdown.

for instance: user select country; then go straight to the next page where there is a dropdown already selected the country value. then only they can do the next process...

note:(list item in the dropdown is same as the 1st)

hope anyone can help me.

thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you can use session or cookie to save country drop down value and use in next page.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can store the first-page dropdown values in Session or Cookies. If you have less important things like country, cities, and address locations then you can simply use the Cookies to store the data.

Comment: Thanks, Bro I Tried But Something went wrong can you please let me know how to store value in session or cookies and call on another page.... I am creating a project in Codeigniter as I already posted the question but nobody answers the link is : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58092568/get-the-value-of-selected-dropdown-and-pass-it-to-another-dropdown-as-selected-i

Answer (score 0):

You can use url parameter to pass the selected value from one page to another.

```
http://www.test.com/next_page.php?selected_value=12
```

Like above example you can pass the selected drop down value to another page in php.

You can use

```
$_GET['selected_value']
```

in next page to get selected value.

Comment: thanks, Shankar but the selected dropdown is in popup model thats why the selected value is not showing in URL

Comment: bro what to write in $_GET['    ']

Answer (score 0):

You have to get select value by doing `onChange` event via jquery.

After jquery, you need to pass that value to particular change event.

Lets say you have this select box

```
<select id="select1">
<option value"">Select</option>
<option value"1">A</option>
<option value"1">b</option>
<option value"1">C</option>
</select>
```

While if any value changes you need to navigate to that page taking that option value.

So this is how you can do it via jquery.

```
$("#select1").change(function(){
  //alert();
  var changedval = $(this).val();
  var url = "pagename/countryname="+changedval;
  window.location.href= url;
  /* $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            data: {'image_name': image_name, 'id' : id},
            success: function (data) {
                $("#profile_picture_display_outer").hide();
            },
            error: function (data) {
            }
        });  */
});
```

You can even get values via ajax as well or you can directly redirect to that particular url via appending current selected value.

Additional if you are using Codeigniter 3 then this is how you can mention routes in routes.php

```
$route['pagename/(:any)'] = 'Controller/methodname/$1';
```

Comment: Bro I Write Code and I am New in Codeigniter the question link is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58092568/get-the-value-of-selected-dropdown-and-pass-it-to-another-dropdown-as-selected-i  can you please help me